# Java International Address Parsing

Tags: java, internationalization

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good Java API for parsing addresses from various locales? This is an international app that needs to work in various places like Saudi Arabia and Germany.

Desolate

Comment: not sure but dont think there is one that contains all. Someone will answer if there is :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java postal address parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877742/java-postal-address-parser)

Comment: systempuntout > I've read through that and didn't find much of use. One of the solutions put forward was a web based service, which I want to avoid if I can

Comment: I should also mention that I'm on a rather old JDK for the mobile platform, so I don't have JDK 5 or 6, which JGeocoder requires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following: [Parse usable Street Address, City, State, Zip from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string)

[Regular expression for parsing mailing addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642602/regular-expression-for-parsing-mailing-addresses)

It seems that library you are looking for is not implemented yet. Probably you will implement it? :) I believe links I posted here can help you. Good luck.

Sorry. Here is yet another link: [Java postal address parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877742/java-postal-address-parser)

It is very useful! Go on this first.

Comment: unfortunately I'm on an old JDK (1.2) and don't have regular expressions available to me. Thaks for getting back to me though

Comment: Not much use for **internationalized** parsing.